# Как отправить сообщение от телеграм-бота в виде ссылки-команды?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Здравствуйте.
Знаю про разновидности кнопок - url, switch и т.д., но не могу найти ответ на свой вопрос, точнее как сделать следующее:
Как отправить сообщение пользователю от бота в формате ссылки-команды (я не знаю как правильно она называется).
Например, что бы от бота пришло сообщение: 
посмотреть(данное слово выделено как ссылка синим цветом) новости

Так вот, пользователь должен нажать на слово "посмотреть", боту отправляется команда /посмотреть, я её ловлю и обрабатываю. 
Как мне пользователю отправить такое сообщение???

Пример:
[image: пример бота]

дополнительный вопрос к @Alex78191.
Если выполнить команду `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "/command")`, то результатом будет сообщение от бота в виде команды, пример:
[image: отображается как команда]

А если выполнить таким образом (реальный пример):

```
mess = row[1].strip()+" "+row[2].strip()
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "/"+mess)
```

то результат будет такой:
[image: отображается как обычный текст]
то есть сообщение будет отображаться как обычный текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это обычный текст. Просто отправьте команды со слешем.

> Приложения Telegram будут: подсвечивать /команды в сообщениях. При
>   нажатии на такую подсвеченную команду, она будет сразу же отправлена
>   боту.
>   https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots#commands

Команды должны быть написаны латиницей.

> Команда должна начинаться с символа косой черты «/» и не может быть
>   длиннее 32 символов. Команды могут состоять из букв латинского
>   алфавита, цифр и подчёркивания. https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots#commands

https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands

Comment: Капец, решение оказалось на поверхности и о чём я только думал))))  Спасибо большое

Comment: так работает: `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="/command")`  а так не работает: `mess="command"; bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="/"+mess`Не подскажите решение?

Comment: @Cenzor что такое mess?

Comment: в переменную mess записываю строку 'command', потом уже с помощью конкатенации строк "/"+mess получаю значение переменной text = "/command". Но тогда это сообщение отправляется как обычный текст, не в виде команды

Comment: @Cenzor Покажите как записываете

Comment: так и записываю mess='command'

Comment: @Cenzor что это за библиотека?

Comment: а потом bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="/" +mess).  Вот так как раз выводится сообщение /command как простой текст

Comment: библиотека  telebot

Comment: @Cenzor зачем ты пишешь `text =`?

Comment: добавил суть обсуждения в комментариях к основному телу вопроса.

Comment: @Cenzor обновил ответ. Не надо писать, что это вопрос ко мне, это вопрос ко всем.

Answer (score 0):

Для форматирования строк используйте функцию `format()`

как и откуда формируется текст сообщения с коммандами? это шаблон или динамическое меню?

что содержит переменная `row`?

```
mess = row[1].strip()+" "+row[2].strip()
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "/"+mess)
```

почему отправляется только комманда, без текста? какая вообще точная задача?

```
mess = '/{} {}'.format(row[1].strip(), row[2].strip())
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)
```

это как вариант. в идеале - нужно смотреть весь код.